Bind9 Managed-Keys-Zone: Unable to Fetch DNSKEY Set '.'
root@eugene-QEMU-Virtual-Machine:/etc# sudo rndc managed-keys status
view: _default
next scheduled event: Wed, 10 Jul 2024 08:06:51 GMT
name:
keyid: 20326
algorithm: RSASHA256
flags: SEP
next refresh: Wed, 10 Jul 2024 08:06:51 GMT
trusted since: Wed, 10 Jul 2024 05:57:51 GMT
root@eugene-QEMU-Virtual-Machine:/etc#
It seems my Bind9 server is unable to fetch the DNSKEY set for the root zone. Can anyone suggest what steps I should take to resolve this issue?I tried to ping my website and it said host was unreachable.
